# Consulta MySQL con varios inner join

Tags: mysql

como va? Les comento que tengo un problema en una consulta sobre la BD. Mi objetivo es obtener una tabla con los ascensores que no tengan hecho el mantenimiento el mes actual y que la fecha de mantenimiento desde y hasta, esten en un rango (uso el numero 2 a modo de ejemplo). Las tablas que participan son las siguientes:

Cliente: codCliente (CP), domicilio, numeroDomicilio, fechaMantenimientoDesde, fechaMantenimientoHasta.

Ascensor: idAscensor (CP), numeroAscensor.

Mantenimiento: idMantenimiento (CP), fecha. <-- esta fecha es la del mantenimiento hecho

Asi queda mi consulta:

```
select cl.domicilio, cl.numerodomicilio, asce.numeroasc 
from cliente as cl inner join ascensor as asce
    on cl.codcliente = asce.codcliente
inner join mantenimiento as mant
    on asce.idascensor = mant.idascensor
where 16 between cl.fechamantenimientodesde and cl.fechamantenimientohasta
and month(mant.fecha) <> 2 or month(mant.fecha) is null;
```

El tema es que quiero que devuelva solo los que NO tienen el mantenimiento hecho el mes 2, osea, el mantenimiento en el mes 2 seria nulo, no se si me logro explicar.

Comment: tiene pinta de un problema con parentesis. prueba a añadirlos entre el ultimo and y el final de consulta, algo como: `and (month(mant.fecha) <> 2 or month(mant.fecha) is null);`

Comment: El tema es que no se si estoy haciendolo bien. Me explico nuevamente. Puede que no existan mantenimientos cargados para un ascensor, como hago para traer todos los ascensores que no tienen mantenimiento cargado? No se como consultar algo que no existe. Se entiende?

Comment: Podes simplificar muchisimo este problema, y de paso ayudarnos a ayudarte. Olvidate de todas los joins en un principio y concentrate en una sola tabla, la de mantenimiento. Busca en esa tabla los registros que queres.

Comment: Buenisimo, supongamos que ahora pido todas los manteminientos. Listo, ahora quiero saber todos los ascensores que NO estan en esa tabla de todos los mantenimientos, como seria?

Comment: Te animo a que incluyas el SQL para generar las tablas con algún dato y así podamos ayudarte, de esta forma podremos enviarte la consulta depurada y funcionando. A mí ayuda mucho ver el diagrama de la base de datos completa para ubicarme.